# recycleView Item Scaaned in Editext then Image should Visible

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, adapter

There a simple question if u have a knowledge recycle view items, M a newbie in android world.I have a recycleview adapter that data is set through ArrayList API Call. [There's a Photo that has data in recycle view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYhYI.jpg)

I want whenever item is scanned in ItemID EditText, the item in recycle view color will change and the image should visible.It only visible when the edittext value and recycle value item is same like that Image can explain it well than my words.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMwbj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still unclear regarding exactly what you are trying to achieve. However, as per my understandings, I think you are trying to highlight the adapter view with the entered **ItemID** in the `EditText`.

There can be two ways of getting the **ItemID** in the `EditText` as per your attached image 1:

- By manually entering the item ID and then pressing the plus button
- By invoking a scanning activity which scans a BarCode or QR Code and then returns the ItemID in the `onActivityResult` method of the current activity. The scanning activity can be launched by pressing the plus button

In both the cases, Once you have the **ItemID**, you need to search your adapter for the passed **ItemID** and then change the background color or add an `imageview` with a tick mark or highlight the view and refresh the adapter in the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Enter ItemID and it is same as in recycle view then the item in recycleview should highlighted and tickmark should visible

Comment: there is no  matter of it call by plus button or by scanning